# How to insert date type when integratting between Hibernate and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, date, javabeans

I 'm using Hibernate framework as way of mapping from Javabean to Database for my project which applied by Spring framework.But, I don' know how to insert Date type in Hibernate

My code :

- User class:

> ```
> import java.util.Date;
> ......................................
>
>  @Column(name = "date")
>   private Date date;
>
>  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
>  public void setDate(String date) {
>   Date date1 = new Date(date);
>   this.date = date1;
> }
> ```

- My register.jsp

  ```
          <tr>
              <td><form:label path="date">Date</form:label></td>
              <td><form:input path="date" /></td>
          </tr>
  ```

After submitting.date fileds in databse is null. It's value can not be mapped into Account table in database

Note: Account means :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class User {
```

Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also has this problem.When I insert date type object into DB,it turns out null value.

My date type in DB is Datetime type.In my case,it is format problem.

Then I try to do so,then solved it,after following formatting.

```
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat spl=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String d=spl.format(date);
date=spl.parse(d);
```

You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

in your User class use the following to map the column as date type

```
@Column(name = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
```